# I am getting fatal exception when applicaion tries to call setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) the code is designed in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
package com.itech.letsshare

import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.genonbeta.android.framework.widget.PowerfulActionMode
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import java.util.jar.Manifest

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var toolbar:Toolbar
    lateinit var send:Button
    lateinit var receive:Button
    lateinit var mdrawer:DrawerLayout
    lateinit var mNavigation:NavigationView
    lateinit var mActionbar: PowerfulActionMode
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        findViews()
        checkpermission()
        setuptoolbar()
    }

    private fun setuptoolbar() {
        val title= toolbar as Toolbar?
        setSupportActionBar(title)
        title?.title="letsShare"
    }

    private fun findViews() {
        toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        send=findViewById(R.id.send)
        receive=findViewById(R.id.receive)
        mdrawer=findViewById(R.id.mDrawer)
        mNavigation=findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        mActionbar=findViewById(R.id.powerful_action_mode)
    }

    private fun checkpermission(): Boolean {
       val permission1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        val permission2=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext,android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
       var result = permission1== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permission2==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        return result
    }

}
```

logcat:

```
2020-10-08 14:11:57.752 23141-23141/com.itech.letsshare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.itech.letsshare, PID: 23141
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.itech.letsshare/com.itech.letsshare.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #68: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #68: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.itech.letsshare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class ImageView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class ImageView
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f03027b a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:944)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4730)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:176)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:171)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:74)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:69)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:199)
2020-10-08 14:11:57.760 23141-23141/com.itech.letsshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:119)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:222)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:385)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:239)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:122)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.itech.letsshare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        <com.genonbeta.android.framework.widget.PowerfulActionMode
            android:id="@+id/powerful_action_mode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="80">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="210dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#00555555">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/send"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:text="@string/send"
                    android:background="#3F70D1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/size_large"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/send"
                    android:orientation="vertical"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/receive"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:text="@string/receive"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:background="#3F70D1"
                    android:layout_below="@id/llLayout"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        style="?navigationViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_main" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

here is nav_header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/layout_profile_picture_image_default"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/layout_profile_picture_image_preferred"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?round" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:background="?rippleColor"
            android:padding="3dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit_24"
            app:tint="@android:color/white"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

    </FrameLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_default_device_name_text"
        style="16sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/unknown"
        android:textColor="#fff" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried using facebooksdk but it doesn't work  the error is at calling setcontentview function...
compile and minsdk version are 30 and 14 respectively
please help me with this issue as soon as possible
This issue is happening for the very first time with me and i also can't understand the error in this
Thanks

Comment: Do you have material design lib dependency added in `build.gradle`?

Comment: if you are talking about implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1' then yes

Comment: Add nav_header layout with question . There can be some issue in it on line #23: Error inflating class ImageView.

Comment: Could you remove the headerLayout and style from NavigationView in XML and try again? Also, how does your drawer_main look?

Comment: i have added nav_header.xml in question please have a look at that

Comment: yes it is running fine when i removed navigation view but i need that in my app